# Error using @import sass function in Next.js App

Tags: webpack, sass, next.js

I am trying to use the sass/scss import function in a standard Create Next App to combine multiple stylesheets together into one main.scss file.

However, I get the error

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently
>   no loaders are configured to process this file. See
>   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> > @import 'abstracts/mixins'; | @import 'abstracts/variables';

I have included the next.config.js file according the Next.js documentation:

```
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
module.exports = withSass({
  /* config options here */
});
```

How do I fix the next.config.js file so that it handles the sass @import keyword?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is valid (it is absolute right now).
Do you import other scss / sass files or css?

Comment: Also, confirm if you've installed `node-sass`

Answer (score 0):

That error message explaining that your sass file need another loader dependency in order to make it works in your application, because you have imported another file in your sass file but the format is not in sass.

You can take a look on the [example](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader), they even use more than one loader: sass-loader, css-loader, and style-loader.

You need to find out what kind of loader do you need for importing that dependency in your sass file.

Hope this help.